# Unable to find nan value in numpy array even though it exists

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, nan

[image: The problem that I am facing]

`brands` is a numpy array with 2314 elements. I am checking if there is a nan value in the array. The output shows false but when I tried intersection function with `np.nan`, it shows the common element as nan. So how come I cant find the nan value in array? And how do I remove it?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that numpy's nan cannot be compared to itself, or in other words `numpy.nan == numpy.nan` returns False. Use instead `numpy.isnan()`.

Answer (score 2):

NaN is not equal with itself.

```
>>> np.nan != np.nan
True
```

You can use [`numpy.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) to check

```py
np.isnan(brands)
```

To remove `nan`, you can use

```py
brands = brands[~np.isnan(brands)]
```